# Text in left is within container and image is out of container

Tags: html, css

How can I design this part with html and css, when I have design like this image:
[image]

Text is within container, but image in the right is out of container

Comment: keep the image as `background-image` of a parent `div` and `position` it to right side using `background-position` property then add a `container` and keep your text in `50%` wide div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can check this snippet I have tried. Hope it will help :

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.full-width-bg {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.left {
  padding: 20px 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.right img {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width-bg">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      <p>Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello
        123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123 Hello 123
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="right"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/800x200/fafafa/000" /></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Sahil Dhir, the idea is that this part I have to design with <img src...> not with background-image.

Comment: Kindly check this on full page.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you. But you need to work-around for the `height`. As currently the height comes from the text content.

```css
.parent {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-640-480-3.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top right;
  background-size: 50% 100%;
}

.text-bg {
  color: #fff;
  background: navy;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 text-bg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 image-bg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```